# How to stop website localizing the timezone for me automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, time-zone, regional-settings

I'm currently living in Hong Kong where the timezone is UTC+8.

Now I'm travelling to Germany and I'm planning some activities. For example I would like to watch a football match and tried to check the fixtures online. Sadly, the displayed time are automatically convert to my local timezone (UTC+8), which makes completely no sense for my planning purpose.

I've checked my windows regional setting and it does not store any information regarding my current location, nor does the browser did. I've tried Chrome, Firefox, IE, and without signing in to google. I'm not sure why the browsers is able to determine my timezone automatically while I did not provide any information at all.

Is there any method (e.g. browser extension) which allows me to override the automatically timezone shifting?

Update:

As an example, the time displayed on http://int.soccerway.com/?ICID=TN_01 are all in my local timezone (UTC+8). If I change my windows timezone, the displayed time will be changed accordingly. Can I force the displayed time to be in specific timezone? (without changing my windows timezone setting)

Comment: 'Sadly, the displayed time" where? on the website? if so there's nothing you can do

Answer (score 2):

Based on your information it's most likely javascript on the planner which picks your local timezone (it's checked/calculated on the client - your PC).

To change it, go to Date/Time properties (or simply double click on the clock - see here for more details http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-clock#1TC=windows-7) and change your timezone to desired one (German in your case). **You need to restart your browser to pick up the change.**

As changing timezone permanently(or switching back and forth) may be inconvenient, you probably could create another user with your desired settings  and then just run your preferred browser in the context of that user (<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>right click</kbd> and select 'run as different user'). *Disclaimer: I have not tested it.*

Additional note: Windows can show up to 3 clocks which you may find useful (information on how to setup in the linked article)

Comment: yes, changing the timezone on my PC actually change the displayed timezone in browser. Annoying but it works..